# Printing Google Maps Directions On One Page (Map Beside Instructions)

Tags: printing, google-maps, page

So I care about the environment and also value my time. I'm often in a dilemma where I have to choose between printing directions on 3 pages of paper or writing them out which takes about 10 minutes.

For example, I just went to print today on Google Maps, and it has:

- One full page for the map, which was largely vertical and took up only a tiny piece of the page (less than half).
- One full page for almost all of the directions. Which took up less than half of that page.
- One full page for the very last direction, with 95% of it wasted.

This should all easily fit on one page, but I wasn't able to make it do so. Anything I tried to do from the Developer Toolbar to change the width of the map in the printing page, it still took the whole screen width and often ended up breaking it so I couldn't see the visual.

I thought it might be easy to just copy the directions into Microsoft Word, but that really messes up since the directional arrows are part of much larger images. Saving the HTML and opening in Word is worse.

I can pretty easily eliminate the third page, but is there any easy way to get a map alongside the directions in Google Maps? Kind of turn it into a two-column table that takes up one page.

Answer (score 1):

If you can arrange everything you need on-screen (perhaps opening only one of the alternate directions), make a screen-shot and paste that into an image editor such as MS *Paint*, Linux *[GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/)* or *[IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/)*, then print from that application. An advantage of this is that you can adjust contrast and crop the image for best printing.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I think this would work too, with two screenshots moved into the image editor, although I usually find it harder to arrange and print from image editing programs. Definitely could be useful to adjust and tweak the image, or if someone didn't have a Microsoft Office equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I came up with is to:

- take a screenshot of the map (Alt + Printscreen),
- open Microsoft Word with a new document,
- set the page layout to Landscape,
- paste (Ctrl + V) and crop the map screenshot,
- take a screenshot of the instructions (Alt + Printscreen),
- paste that in Microsoft Word, and
- crop it to fit side by side with the map.

Answer (score 0):

Unless they’ve changed it since the last time I used it, when you want to print directions, there is a checkbox whether or not to include the large map.  And if you omit the small maps of each turn, the text parts will be slightly smaller.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is tell the print option to print multiple pages per page, and then increase the 'scale' so that the instructions are the full width of each page. Then it looks like multiple columns. :-)